# Why this media query only working with max-width=1000px?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In the code below, I am trying to change the flex feature of a set of navigation links defined in the nav element (class name: flex-nav) when the screen size is of maximum width of 1000px, which works. But when I decrease the maximum width to 900px or so, there is no change in the navigation bar.

Also, when the screen width decreases to 500px, the flex feature of nav element is again changed and some more CSS is applied to change the order of the flex items of the wrapper container(wrapper is the class-name of div container containing all the html tags), but no changes can be seen. Please help me in solving this problem.

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(260deg, #2376ae 0%, #c16ecf 100%);
}

a {
  color: white;
  font-weight: 100;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 20px 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

a:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.toggleNav {
  display: none;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

input {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 0;
}

section,
footer {
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 100;
}


/* Flex Container */

.flex-nav ul {
  border: 1px solid black;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}


/* Flex Item */

.flex-nav li {
  flex: 3;
}

.flex-nav .social {
  flex: 1;
}

@media all and (max-width:1000px) {
  .flex-nav ul {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .flex-nav li {
    flex: 1 1 50%;
  }
  .flex-nav .social {
    flex: 1 1 25%;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width:500px) {
  .flex-nav li {
    flex-basis: 100%;
  }
  /* Turn on flexbox */
  .wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  /* Reorder items */
  .wrapper>* {
    order: 999;
  }
  /* Nav */
  .flex-nav {
    order: 1;
  }
  .toggleNav {
    display: block;
  }
  .flex-nav ul {
    display: none;
  }
  .flex-nav ul.open {
    display: flex;
  }
  /* Header */
  .top {
    order: 2;
  }
  /* Details */
  .details {
    order: 3;
  }
  /* Sign Up */
  .signup {
    order: 4;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>FlexBox Nav</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="wrapper">

    <header class="top">
      <h1><a href="#">What The Flexbox?!</a></h1>
    </header>

    <nav class="flex-nav">
      <a href="#" class="toggleNav">☰ Menu</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Item 01</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 02</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 03</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 04</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 05</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 06</a></li>
        <li class="social">
          <a href="http://twitter.com/wesbos"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li class="social">
          <a href="http://facebook.com/wesbos.developer"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li class="social">
          <a href="http://github.com/wesbos"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li class="social">
          <a href="http://instagram.com/wesbos"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <section class="hero">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1000/600/abstract">
    </section>

    <section class="details">
      <p>A simple video course to help you master FlexBox.</p>
      <p>Sign up today to grab all the videos and exercises!</p>
    </section>

    <section class="signup">
      <form action="" class="signup">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Your Name">
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address">
        <input type="submit" value="Sign me up!">
      </form>
    </section>

    <footer>
      <p>&copy; Crugar</p>
    </footer>


  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('.toggleNav').on('click', function() {
        $('.flex-nav ul').toggleClass('open');
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What "isn't working"? We have no idea what you are expecting to see, and rather than us go through all of your code, can you edit your description to tell us what isn't happening?

Comment: That's not true? I just ran your snippet in "Full page" and `@media all and (max-width:1000px)` works for width 501px - 1000px.

Comment: The code runs for max-width:1000px, but any value less than it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are looking for, but what I can understand from the above context is, try using @media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) and @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) instead of @media all and (max-width:1000px) and @media all and (max-width:500px). This might solve your problem...

Comment: tip : use code samples to determine codes and make it more readable

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your solution worked. But, can you tell me why wasn't @media all not working in the above code.

Comment: The names chosen for CSS media types reflect target devices for which the relevant properties make sense. In the following list of CSS media types the names of media types are normative, but the descriptions are informative. Likewise, the "Media" field in the description of each property is informative.

All --- Suitable for all devices and is default one. If you are picking this then it is being used as a default no matter what screen it is...........

screen --- Used for computer screens, tablets, smart-phones etc.